# jQuery iframe popup and post form to parent

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to create a popup search box. I am using thickbox iframe content. In the popup there are also some other form post when the popup stays and save data. But i want when the main form (fm-form) is submitted then the post action is the parent and shows search result in the parent(popup closes). How can I do this? can i use any other popup? 
[See this link](http://jumpstartsap.businessnetonline.com/palkey_nextgen_done_by_sonarbangla/)

Please see the above url and click on "**New Search**" to have an idea. Again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `target`-attribute of the form to `"_parent"`

Comment: Its not working. I have used action="", set target="_blank". But no luck. Now I want to do this thing: submit the form and make a query which is saved to a session. After closing the thickbox(click on submit), I want the parent to be reloaded so I can get the session. I have tried --onclick="self.parent.tb_remove();"-- in submit button. But the parent is not refreshing. if i click on the close button on the top, then the parent is refreshing.